# Xbindkeys updates only after reboot

Tags: xbindkeys

I am making a desktop application by using xbindkeys underhood, so I want to xbindkeys hotkeys be updated without reboot of computer. Now I should run `xbindkeys -p` and do reboot to update it and work with latest configurations. Is there any way of doing this without reboot ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A shortcut that starts your application?

Comment: No, I am looking for way of updating xbindkeys without reboot. For ex: I did some changes on my .xbindkeys file and my last changes should work WITHOUT reboot. Thanks